# My xfce settings are greyed out

Tags: linux, settings, xfce

My settings are greyed out after uninstalling a GNOME [i don't remember...] package.
Then rebooted and saw that my settings won't open.
I tried searching for GNOME packages on pamac but i don't know which one it is

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide what distro of Linux and what version. Assuming you are using yum install, simply run the following (or dnf history if using dnf):

```
yum history
```

Then simply reinstall what you removed. Hope this helps.